# Assembly \0 character does'nt terminate the String

Tags: assembly

I am learning assembly and was trying some code. this is the code:

```
  1 global _start
  2 
  3 section .data
  4     msg db "HelloWo",0,10,117
  5     lenmsg equ $-msg
  6 
  7 section .text
  8 _start:
  9     mov eax , 4
 10     mov ebx , 1
 11     mov ecx , msg
 12     mov edx , lenmsg
 13     int 0x80
 14     mov eax ,1
 15     mov ebx ,0
 16     int 0x80
```

i was expecting that the output be `HelloWo` since there is a NULL (\0) after `"o"` but all the characters print out to the console and the output is:

```
HelloWo
u
```

i am making and running the executable with these commands:

```
nasm -f elf32 tes.asm -o tes.o
[[ -f tes.o ]] && ld -m elf_i386 tes.o -o tes
[[ -f tes ]] && ./tes
```

where is my misunderstanding?
am i mixing C with Assembly?

Comment: Terminating strings with NUL bytes is a C language convention.  The `write` system call just writes bytes, it doesn't care what their values are.

Comment: @fuz oh! thank you. this can be the answer

Comment: You're the one providing the length, so it's just doing what you asked.

Comment: Btw, the write os primitive is used for writing binary to a file as well as text to a console. For binary data, zeros are part of the data, so the length is what to go by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `int 0x80` with `eax` = `4` cared for your null terminator, then it would not be requiring you to supply the length of your string in `edx`.  The fact that it does require the length of the string in `edx` is a strong indication that it does not care for null terminators, it just prints as many characters as you told it to print, regardless of what these characters are.

Comment: It's not a C vs. assembly issue; you'd have the same problem using a `write` system call in C with `static char msg[] = "HelloWo\0\nu"` (but without a terminating 0 at the end).  Or with C stdio `fwrite`.  As you say, it's mixing explicit-length strings/buffers vs. implicit-length C strings, or of using `sizeof()`  (in this case `$-msg`) instead of `strlen`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, that is right. My "yes" statement is just meant to answer the OP's question "am i mixing C with Assembly?"

Comment: I'm disagreeing with that "yes", and explaining why: Implicit-length 0-terminated strings are a concept that exists in assembly, too.  And explicit-length strings and buffers are a concept that exists in C, along with the `write` system-call (whose [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) actually uses C, like all other Linux system call documentation).  It's mixing those that's the problem, not C and assembly.

Comment: I don't see a good argument for exactly how we could say they're mixing C and asm; they'd have the same bug if they wrote the same code in C with a `char` array containing a `0` byte, and output it with `fwrite` or `write` (rather than a C-string function like `puts`)

Comment: @PeterCordes it is not worth arguing about it, so I just removed that sentence.

Comment: Thanks, now I can upvote your nice answer that clearly explains the actual details. :)